# Mi modal con video aparece en blanco

Tags: javascript, html

Gracias por tomar el tiempo de leerme, mi modal se muestra en blanco cuando se carga la página, el resto de mis modales que funcionan al hacer click funcionan perfectamente.

Mi código HTML

```
        <a title="Video promocional Salsas Harvest Of Love" data-toggle="modal" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nxLtwE0Rr0k?rel=0?autoplay=1" data-target="#videoModal3" class="text-color video-modal"><i class="ti-control-play bg-gradient hover-shadow btn-play mr-2"></i><span>Ver video</span></a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content border-0 rounded-0">
              <iframe width="560" height="315" src="" id="video3" frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Mi script declarado al final de body

```
<script>
  $('#videoModal3').modal('show');
</script>
```

Mi script declarado en un documento externo con terminación .js (este mismo código funciona para el resto de mis modales al hacer click)

```
$('#videoModal3').on('hide.bs.modal',function(e){$("#video3").attr('src',$videoSrc);})
```

Comment: puede que el video que pones no esté bien referenciado en dónde está ubicado

Comment: Adicional a lo que indican en el comentario anterior, ¿sale algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: El script para mostrar el modal debería estar debajo del externo, para que el evento se asigne y funcione... bueno, en teoría. xD

Comment: El src esta vacio

Comment: Perdonen, olvidé poner una línea de código que va antes de lo que va en el HTML en la pregunta, es:
  `<a title="Video promocional Salsas Harvest Of Love" data-toggle="modal" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nxLtwE0Rr0k?rel=0?autoplay=1" data-target="#videoModal3" class="text-color video-modal"><i class="ti-control-play bg-gradient hover-shadow btn-play mr-2"></i><span>Ver video</span></a>`

Comment: La consola no muestra ningún error

Comment: Por favor espero tu pregunta añadiendo eso

Comment: muchas gracias, ya está añadido en la pregunta, lo edité hace rato

Comment: Inserta la parte de `js` que usas para mostrar el modal y que en el contenedor cargue el témplate que contiene el video ya que veo en tu código que los datos los envías por data. ejemplo `data-src`

Comment: Si al final de la página haces el  $('#videoModal3').modal('show'); el modal se abre, pero el iframe no tiene nada en el src. Luego supongo que al hacer click en el link para abrir el modal tienes que agregar el valor data-src al src del iframe, quizás en el evento modal.before.open. Es una idea.

Comment: Muchas gracias, sus comentarios me ayudaron a entender mejor como funcionaba el script y lo que hacía cada una de sus partes. No se usar JS, sólo HTML y CSS, creo le di exitosamente la vuelta al problema. Les comparto como lo solucioné en el apartado de respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cree una div con un ID nuevo que dejara de usar la función declarada en el documento aparte, osea este código:

```
$('#videoModal3').on('hide.bs.modal',function(e){$("#video3").attr('src',$videoSrc);})
```

Por defult esta div al tener la class="modal fade" no se ve, este fué el código

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content border-0 rounded-0">
          <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nxLtwE0Rr0k?rel=0?autoplay=1" id="video3" frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

y declaré al final de body el mismo script con el nuevo id

```
<script>
  $('#videoModal4').modal('show');
</script>
```